# Pandas - how to slice value_counts?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to slice a pandas value_counts() :

```
>sur_perimetre[col].value_counts()
44341006.0    610
14231009.0    441
12131001.0    382
12222009.0    364
12142001.0    354
```

But I get an error :

```
> sur_perimetre[col].value_counts()[:5]
KeyError: 5.0
```

The same with ix :

```
> sur_perimetre[col].value_counts().ix[:5]
KeyError: 5.0
```

How would you deal with that ?

### EDIT

Maybe :

```
pd.DataFrame(sur_perimetre[col].value_counts()).reset_index()[:5]
```

Comment: Use `iloc`, i.e. `sur_perimetre[col].value_counts().iloc[:5]`

Comment: I just tried, both `ix` and `iloc` work fine.

Comment: `sur_perimetre[col].value_counts()[:5]` gives me the top 5 values in pandas 0.18.0. But it is better to be explicit. I'd go with `.iloc` too.

Comment: @romain, whats your pandas version? I am using 0.17.1 and direct slicing is working for me too.

Comment: Ah ok, it is because the values are floats. When they are integers, it works fine. Maybe a bug?

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**

You need to observe that value_counts() returns a Series object. You can process it like any other series and get the values. You can even construct a new dataframe out of it.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,4,5], columns=['C1'])

In [3]: vc = df.C1.value_counts()

In [4]: type(vc)
Out[4]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [5]: vc.values
Out[5]: array([2, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [6]: vc.values[:2]
Out[6]: array([2, 1])

In [7]: vc.index.values
Out[7]: array([3, 5, 4, 2, 1])

In [8]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':vc.index, 'count':vc.values})

In [8]: df2
Out[8]: 
   count  value
0      2      3
1      1      5
2      1      4
3      1      2
4      1      1
```

**Method2:**

Then, I was trying to regenerate the error you mentioned. But, using a single column in DF, I didnt get any error in the same notation as you mentioned.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,4,5], columns=['C1'])

In [3]: df['C1'].value_counts()[:3]
Out[3]: 
3    2
5    1
4    1
Name: C1, dtype: int64      

In [4]: df.C1.value_counts()[:5]
Out[4]: 
3    2
5    1
4    1
2    1
1    1
Name: C1, dtype: int64

In [5]: pd.__version__
Out[5]: u'0.17.1'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I believe [ iloc ] is the function I was looking for